# Word for a part of a city that is under the control of organized crime?

Tags: single-word-requests

Sample use: "Timmy went to ??? to procure an 8-ball of cocaine and visit his favorite hooker."

Sort of like chinatown is a general name for an ethnic enclave, is there a general  word or a phrase for a criminal enclave?

It is best demonstrated in 80s/90s Japanese gangster movies where the Yakuza often  replaced rule of law in a part of a city that contained illegal gambling, prostitution, etc. The Yakuza didn't just run the businesses but in fact replaced the police in those areas, had their own enforcers, laws and judges.

I found a few terms like mobtown or narco town but those seem to be referring to entire towns/cities, not just parts of it.

Hood or ghetto don't necessarily mean control by a criminal element.

Comment: A common phrase is [no-go area](https://www.google.com/search?q=no-go+areas+in+leicester) as that does actually refer to the police staying out of it and criminal elements taking over, but that won't fit your sentence. [Note: I've nothing against Leicester; Google autocomplete filled in the city name and the first result at that link is relevant.]

Comment: “Outlaw area”  may fit as a generic expression.

Comment: Perhaps "*Timmy went to the X district*" with X being something like *red-light*, *brothel*, or *gangster*. In Japan those districts were called Aosen.

Comment: *Little Amsterdam* ...

Comment: Mob neighborhoods. But they're not places you go to score drugs. The streets are clean and crime free. The mob polices those neighborhoods.

Answer (score 1):

While [**gangland**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gangland) is most often used as an adjective or an attributive noun, as in, *a gangland killing*, it can be used to describe a specific territory controlled by gangs. Per the Urban Dictionary:

> **gangland**
>   Territory owned and controlled by major street gangs.
>   *“Don't be stepping up into that 'zoo', that's major gangland.”*

See also https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Citations:gangland#English

- **ganglands**: soc.culture.african.american - 19 Apr 1992 by Stanford Guillory
  *She has garnered national acclaim because her neighborhood is in the center of the ganglands of LA.*

While this use is rarer, it is attested. If you were to write “Timmy went down to gangland,” a typical reader would understand that you meant that literally, that Timmy went into the turf of some gang, rather than just figuratively.